# Module `fs` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: node.js, react-native, azure-iot-hub

I'm new to Node.js and `react-native`. I followed the sample on [send_telemetry.js](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-node/blob/master/iot-hub/Samples/device/send_telemetry.js) exactly but when I run my react-native app I get an error: "The development server returned response error code 500.

the error message is:

> bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `fs` from `ProjectPath\node_modules\azure-iot-device\lib\module_client.js`: Module `fs` does not exist in the Haste module map";

Im running:

- Node.js v10.15.3
- NPM 6.4.1
- react-native@0.59.2

First error was the same with Unable to resolve module `events`, 
I can install events, 
but the fs module is: "This package name is not currently in use, but was formerly occupied by another package. To avoid malicious use, npm is hanging on to the package name, but loosely, and we'll probably give it to you if you want it."

```
var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-http').Http;
var DeviceClient = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

var connectionString = 'my connection string';
var client = DeviceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Protocol);

function ConnectionTest(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Could not connect: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Client connected');
    }
    client.close(function () {
        process.exit(0);
    });
};

export async function Test() {
    client.open(ConnectionTest);
};
```

Basically I need to know how to get the azure IOT hub client working in my react-native app (not using Expo).

Im pretty much stumped so any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: try to open this file `module_client.js` in your node-modules folder ... and see the import||require statement for this `fs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dependency module is missing ... which is [fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs) ...

this file-system npm module is incompatible with **react-native** ... cause it has it own different environment.

Comment: i am aware that that dependency is missing, so is that to say that the azure-iot-device module is incompatible with react-native?

Comment: unfortunately yes, cause `fs` module is meant to handle file-system for node environment like desktop and web ... but mobile's file system is completely different ...

Comment: Thanks, back to the drawing board then

Comment: @Francois ... if you could fork this npm module to use `react-native-fs` instead of this `fs` module .. i guess it could work ... and good luck anyway...

Comment: I will definitely, i did fine another l library that i forked and changed for my purposes

Comment: @Francois glad you find a library that suits your needs :) ... best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had "import { symlink } from 'fs';" randomly pop up in one of my scripts. Once I deleted this line same issue you had went away. I would search your whole project for that line.